# customize contact form to save data to DB

Tags: forms

I'm a newbie for ee2. The template tag "exp:email:contact_form" allow me to create a contact form without save form's data to my DB. I need a contact form that save its data to DB, send a email to my gmail account and then I can browse these contacts in CP Admin. Please show me how to do it. May somebody helps me. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [FreeForm](http://www.solspace.com/software/detail/freeform/) module for this purpose.

Comment: May you share Freeform Pro to me? Thanks.

Comment: From here http://www.solspace.com/software/detail/freeform/ you can download either Free version or purchase Pro version.

Comment: You're right. I had a Free version. I need to test advanced function of Pro version. Thanks.

Comment: Or do you know what module can create a form?

Comment: I think, you should ask to Solspace if they can provide some demo for FreeForm Pro version.